# MS Graph API returns 500 when I try to request MessageRules

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, http-error

I am doing a get request to Microsoft Graph API [List Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messagerules?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
The exact endpoint is:

```
GET /users/{id}/mailFolders/inbox/messageRules
```

I am getting a response of 500 with an empty body.
The headers I get are:

```
{"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 10 May 2023 08:27:30 GMT"]}
```

When I try to get the exact same request, with another `userId`, I get a successful response. Hence it's not a token issue.

What can be for that user that I can't fetch his data?
Is there an header I can set to get a more detailed error?

Comment: Sounds like you may a have corrupted rule, you can use a MAPI editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy to view the rules table and remove any corrupted entries. I'd check the rules carefully as one trick hackers can use is to create rule objects to forward email.